# Using Gmail’s SMTP using @personaldomain.com

Tags: php, smtp

I was wondering if it is possible to use Gmail’s SMTP to send emails from my web host’s provided email address ?
If so, is it possible to use it with PHPMailer ?
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? I must admit that I haven't tried that on my own, but the code is fairly simple and you could check within minutes if it works or not

Comment: I have tried using a Gmail addresss with a gmail SMTP and it works as expected but if I use my own domain with Google's SMTP it doesn't work

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code and exact error messages? Without it, one can only guess about the problem

Answer (score 1):

it's possible,

first of all you have to forward your personaldomain.com to the g-mail from the C-panel by adding mx records in the domain too. And after set the SMTP of the g-mail in to the PHPMailer.

[How to Use Your Domain with Gmail](https://youtu.be/YnTVR1RbrkE)

Comment: hey @BonCoin if my answer is correct then please accept my answer and vote it. Thank you